# Map of the United States of America using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a file which contains all the longitude and latitude for all of the United States of America. Each state is represented by its postal abbreviation. END_ONE_POLY represents ending a single polygon. END_ALL_POLY represents ending the whole polygon of the state. Like this:

```
    -88.1665689999999955 30.2492550000000016
    -88.1884692736000062 30.2469340542000005
     END_ONE_POLY
     END_ALL_POLY
     AR
    -94.4760497582000056 36.4993199124999990
    -94.4568835367000048 36.4993666550000029
```

My task is to create a map of the USA. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk,Canvas
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root = Tk() # Create a window.
canvas = Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bg="white")

data = open("lab313.txt", "r").read().split()
usamain = []
usaisland = []
usa = []
i = 0
makePoly = False

while True:
   if len(data[i]) == 2 and makePoly == False:
      data.remove(data[i])
      makePoly = True
   if data[i] == "END_ONE_POLY":
      data.remove(data[i])
      makePoly = False
   if makePoly == True:
      usamain.append(float(data[i]))
   if data[i] == "END_ALL_POLY":
      data.remove(data[i])
      data.remove(data[i])
      usamain[:] = []
      usaisland[:] = []
      i = 0
      makePoly = False
   if data[i] == "END_FILE":
      break
   if makePoly == False:
      usaisland.append(float(data[i]))
   usa.append(float(data[i]))

   i += 1

i = 0
print usamain
print usaisland
print usa
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However, I'm getting two errors:

```
File "Lab14-1.py", line 17, in <module>
if len(data[i]) == 2 and makePoly == False:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And:

```
File "Lab14-1.py", line 17, in <module>
if data[i] == "END_FILE":
Index Error: list index out of range
```

How would I go about fixing this issue. Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: You can't remove data from a list while you are iterating over it. When you do that it screws up the index for the remaining data. So if you `data.remove(data[i])` then the next `data[i]` is actually `data[i+1]`, and in your case that's beyond the length of the list. Why don't you loop over the lines directly: `for line in data:`?

Comment: could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the complete data (pastebin or similar)? If you do I could solve this with `groupby` in a much neater way.

Comment: I don't think we need the data for all fifty states. One or two states would be more than enough to illustrate the problem.